# Space before and after a character/symbol

Tags: spacing

Suppose I want to define `\newcommand{\versesep}{\textbullet}` to be used to separate, say, Bible verses. What is the suggested method to define the horizontal space before and after the character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this??  Unlike the `\kern` alternative, the `\hspace` will be absorbed at margins, allowing proper alignment/flushing.  The particular numbers for the gap can be chosen by the OP.

Thus use of `minus` (or `plus`) in defining the gapsize allows for some slop to be built in to the gap, which can be useful especially for narrow column documents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\versegap{\hspace{1pt minus.5pt}}
\newcommand\versesep{\versegap\textbullet\versegap}
\textwidth3in
\begin{document}
God created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and

xxxGod created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and

xxxxxxGod created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted to avoid a linebreak following the bullet, then this variation could be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\versegap{\hspace{1pt minus.5pt}}
\def\versekern{\kern\glueexpr1pt minus.5pt\relax}
\newcommand\versesep{\versegap\textbullet\versekern\nobreak}
\textwidth3in
\begin{document}
God created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and

xxxGod created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and

xxxxxxGod created the heavens and the earth,\versesep the earth was a formless void and
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly +1, but could you explain why `\kern\glueexpr1pt` not simply `\kern 1pt`, please?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Using `\glueexpr1pt minus.5pt\relax` allows for the some shrinkage to be be built into the non-breaking gap.